# maple: how to include my library at startup

Tags: shell, math, customization, read-eval-print-loop, maple

Currently I use the math-software "Maple" from the command line, basically as a powerful calculator.
I've written a simple maple "library" that contains my helper functions. I want to load it at maple startup time. (This task is almost equivalent to loading a .bashrc or .bash_profile file at startup of a shell).

How to do this in Maple? It is more complicated than expected, and poorly documented.

What I have right now is a compiled Maple lib in a Maple dir in my home directory.

On a maple shell/REPL I do this to load this file (and then the std lib):

```
libname := "/home/knut/.maple/12/mylibs", "/opt/maple12/lib";
with(knb_ee);
```

*[argumentd, hz2rad, listPhasors, phase, phased, phasorTheta, phasorThetaSum, polard, proc1, proc2, rad2hz]*

I want the two commands above executed at maple startup. HOw to do this?
There is a .maple/12/ dir in my home dir, and there I find a file "maplerc" (this is not a dotfile).  Is this the way to go?

**Update:**
This description from vendor Maplesoft seems misleading to me, because there are no such directories as mentioned below:

> UNIX and Linux
>
> Under UNIX and Linux, the personal initialization file is called
>   .mapleinit, and the global initialization file is called init. The
>   commands in the initialization file will be executed by all users on
>   the network by placing the file in the Maple lib directory, for
>   example, $MAPLE/lib/init.
>
> To execute a user's personal set of commands, the initialization file
>   should be placed in the user's home directory under UNIX, for example,
>   $HOME/.mapleinit.
>
> Maple reads and executes the network initialization file before the
>   personal initialization file.

http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=worksheet/reference/initialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating `/home/knut/.mapleinit` as a new file, containing the commands you want executed.

You ought to already have a home directory for your Linux user account. You should be able to change directory to that location with a command such as,

```
cd ~
```

or,

```
cd $HOME
```

The last one uses the environment variable `HOME`, whose assigned value you might also check by issuing the command `echo $HOME`. From your post it seems that your home directory is `/home/knut`.

Anyway, the simplest way is to create a new file `.mapleinit` in your home directory, and place within that plaintext file the Maple commands you want executed automatically at start up.

That is why the documentation mentions it as `$HOME/.mapleinit` since that file would normally go in your home directory. That file will not exist until you create it manually. That is normal (for Maple).

Even when such an initialization file as `~/.mapleinit` exists, you can still launch without it being utilized by passing the `-s` option to the `maple` script.

Or you can point to any other file of your choice as the initialization file by using the `-i` option. Eg,

```
maple -i somedirectory/somefile
```

Yet another way (slightly trickier if you have to escape quotes) is to use one of more instance of the `-c` option when calling the `maple` script. This is yet another way for you to issue several distinct commands at start up. In fact there are quite a few ways to accomplish your goals.

Comment: thanks for this verbose explanation, but why is there a .maple/12/ directory and a  ~/.maple/12/maplerc file? What goes in there? The settings for the GUI version of maple? Is this file to be edited by the user? Should code for the libraries stored here in this ~/.maple/12/ dir, or in ~/.maple, or elsewhere? (This is almost a second independent question.)

Comment: The directories under ~/.maple/ are not intended for the user. They are where Maple stores saved preferences, and that is all. You should put library files elsewhere. Not under your Maple installation directory either. Put personal library files in a normal, nonhidden directory of your own, and use `libname` to specify it. That is usual. PS, libname:="/home/knut/someplace",libname is more useful as a one-time command since it is independent of your Maple installation specifics.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to omit the "/opt/.." path from the libname assignment but then maple would not start up properly, or some other weird behavior occured.  ----   Besides, there is still surprisingly little talk on the web about best practices for maple customization with .mapleinit (or maple.ini), and about what people put in their .mapleinit files. This is the only one that shows up in a quick self-explanatory google search: http://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/41590-Examples-Of-Mapleini-Files   (and it does not contain any useful advice)

Comment: oh...you, @acer, also contributed to that forum thread on mapleprimes.com (from 2007). Never mind. That contribution is indeed useful. I think I'll ask another question here about module development (mymod.m files and .lib files, savelib() calls etc), when I have given it another try.

Comment: I didn't quote my ealier comment's suggestion, so sorry if it was not clear. It was intended as `libname:="/home/knut/someplace",libname;` so that it prepends your custom library location to the current value of `libname`. In this way it would not have to have the Maple installation location hard-coded.

Comment: On Windows the initialisation file is C:\users\USER\maple.ini